# Determine the solution of $x^4y''=(y')^2+3x^6$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the solution of $x^4y''=(y')^2+3x^6$

My idea: 
suppose $(y')^2=t \to 2y'y''=\frac{dt}{dx}\to y''=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\frac{dt}{dx}$

then equation reduced into $x^4\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\frac{dt}{dx}=t+3x^6$

how to solve from here ig ot no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put $u = \dfrac{y'}{x^2}\implies y'' = 2xu+x^2u' = u^2+3x^2\implies x^2u'=u^2-2xu+x^2+2x^2 = (u-x)^2+2x^2\implies u' = \left(\dfrac{u-x}{x}\right)^2+2 $ . Next put $v = \dfrac{u-x}{x} \implies u = vx+x \implies u' = xv'+v + 1\implies xv'+v+1 = v^2+2\implies xv' = v^2-v+1\implies \dfrac{dv}{v^2-v+1} = \dfrac{dx}{x}$ . Can you take it from here to solve for $v$, then $u$, and finally then $y$ ? I hope it helps...

Comment: @Deepsea..difficulty to sloving

Comment: @Deepsea..solving for v and u and ten y is really diffulty

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more helpful substitution: let $u = y'$. Then, $$x^4u' = u^2+3x^6 \Rightarrow u' = x^{-4}u^2+3x^2$$ This is now a [Riccati equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0123.pdf). Under the further transformation $v(x) = \exp\left[-\int x^{-4}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]$, the equation becomes $$x^2v''+4xv'+3v = 0$$ which is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) with the solution $$v(x) = \frac{c_1\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\log(x)\right)+c_2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\log(x)\right)}{x^{3/2}}$$ Now, back-substitute to get $y$.